# FB api access page

Tags: facebook

I am trying to start with facebook development, following this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2?locale=en_GB

so I pasted this code inside the body tag:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '12323432423',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then I added this as mentioned in the walkthrough:

```
<div  class="fb-like"  data-send="true"  data-width="450"  data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

My question is, is the appId the same as page Id? I am trying to deal with my page on facebook, and to get people to like it or post to iT. Am I going the right way?

This code is not working, I am getting nothing on my page.

Answer (score 1):

No, App ID is an App ID, you need to create one here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Btw, dont forget to add the data-href parameter with your Page URL in the Like Button div.

Comment: Thanks luschn. but how do I get the app to talk to my page? Isn't there a walkthrough for this? now I made an App and I got the ID, but how to deal with my page?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "talk to my page". you just use the page url in the data-href parameter of your like button, that´s all.

Comment: do you have any tutorials for these things?

Comment: what for? there is a generator that gives you all the code you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: Hi luschn, thanks for your help. I have pasted the code for my page here: http://pastebin.com/hbcQdryr the appId is the one I got from Fb, and the data-href is the link for my page. It's not working.

Comment: put it on a webserver and post the test link

Comment: no, a testlink is what i mean, not the code. a link where we could test the code.

Comment: oh, how can I do that? how can I put it online?

Comment: how did you even test it without putting it online?

Comment: On html file on my local machine? I copied the same code I shared and pasted it.

Comment: well...i guess that´s why it does not work. put it on a server and it will.